# Localization in Standard Module

Tags: abp

I'm coding a web application in Abp Framework in italian language.

Is it possible to override the localization string in the standard module of ABP Framework like Account and Identity?

Thanks.
Danilo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should extend existing resources. For example, if you want to extend `TenantManagementResource`, you can extend it like below in your `module.cs` file. And in your localization file you should redefine the same localization keys which you want to override.

```
ConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
    {
        ...
        ...
        Configure<AbpLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            ...
            ...
            options.Resources
                .Get<AbpTenantManagementResource>()
                .AddVirtualJson("/Localization/YourTenantManagementResource");
        });
```